# Perl: test regex without creating new variable

Tags: perl

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I'm somewhat new to perl, and I feel there should be a way to do this, but am having trouble finding any documentation.   I'm wondering if you can do the following without the throw-away variable `$doto`:

```
my $file="foo/bar.c";
my $doto = $file;
$doto =~ s/\.c$/\.o/;
print ".o exists" if ( -f $doto );
```

That is, something like:

```
print ".o exists" if ( -f ($file =~ s/\.c$/\.o/gr) );
```

(but that creates a compile error of course).

My compile error is as follows:

> Bareword found where operator expected at - line 2, near "s/.c$/.o/gr"

This is `perl, v5.8.9`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us about that compile error. Your code works for me when I adapt and try it on 5.26. `$ perl -E 'my $file = "foo.c"; say ".o exists" if -f $file  =~ s/\.c$/\.o/gr;'` compiles, prints nothing. `touch foo.c foo.o && perl -E 'my $file = "foo.c"; say ".o exists" if( -f ($file  =~ s/\.c$/\.o/gr));'` prints an empty line and `.o exists`. With and without the parentheses.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: In this example, I want to test for the existence of a .o file based on the name for a .c file.  But this is more about how to write more maintainable code with fewer variables in general.

Comment: @simbabque:  Hmm, it doesn't work with perl 5.8 (in fact my perl doesn't like the `-E` option...), but if I use stdin with a cut and paste of your code, it complains.  So it's just a version thing.   I can do this with the extra variables, I just wanted to get into the practice of writing neater code...

Comment: 5.8 doesn't have the `/r` flag for substitutions. That was added in 5.14. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution.

Comment: Yes, I just realized the first example as posted, wouldn't work either (I had been trying something from the web).  I've edited the question to use the example I did actually try, though It adds yet another line :-(

Comment: And that my example wouldn't compile makes sense too, because there's no `feature "say"` either. `-E` turns on all the features that are available in your version. Might be that that flag didn't even exist.

Comment: Without `/r` you can't do non-destructive substitution. Only way would be to create a function. If you've got lots of those, that'll work.

Comment: Note that the `/g` modifier is meaningless here and should be omitted.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like v5.8.9 was released over 9 years ago https://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html

Comment: Yes.. unfortunately, this script has to be backwards compatible, as that's the default perl on our systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer talks about making the actual `print if -f` lookup code more readable. If you want the code to run faster, this solution is more expensive than your *ugly* one.

Since in your version of Perl there is no non-destructive substitution all you could do is implement your own function for that. It will not be as nice as the `s///r`, but it does the job. If you've got several occurrences of this type of code, it will make sense.

```
sub replace {
    my ($text, $pattern, $replacement) = @_;

    $text =~ s{$pattern}{$replacement}g; # do you need /g?
    return $text;
}

# ... later

print ".o exists" if -f replace($file, qr/\.c$/, '.o');
```

This already takes care of making a copy for you, much like your temporary variable does, so `$file` will not actually be altered.

Note that your `/g` was useless as the filename will only ever have one end of the line, but it might not be useless later. However, it would be better to not fix it there, but to pass in an optional flag as another argument.

```
replace( $file, qr/.../, '.o', 'g' ); # where 'g' just means any true value

sub replace {
    my ($text, $pattern, $replacement, $global) = @_;

    if ($global) {
         $text =~ s{$pattern}{$replacement}g;
    } else {
         $text =~ s{$pattern}{$replacement};
    }

    return $text;
}
```

You also generally don't need to escape the `.` in the replacement part because that's not actually a regular expression pattern, just a string.

Comment: This reminds me a lot of http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php, but the order of the arguments in my implementation is more Perlish somehow.

Comment: This still uses a temporary variable `$text`; in fact it uses three!

Comment: @Borodin it does. But it's more concise code. I think that was the point, rather than optimizing for performance.

Comment: You can't put `/g` on `qr//`: it's part of the *operation*, not the regex pattern.

Comment: @Borodin true. That doesn't encode into the flags part at the front.

Comment: If the idea is to tighten the code then the OP's version can be reduced to a couple of lines with `(my $doto = $file) =~ s/\.c$/\.o/`

Comment: Thanks, yes -- the idea is to make the code more concise/readable.   I think this is the best solution for my version of perl.

Comment: Might as well use String::Substitution `gsub_copy`/`gsub_modify` instead of that. On top of saving you on code, it supports `$1` and such in the replacement expression!

Comment: @ikegami I didn't even know that!

Comment: (Oops, I meant `sub_modify`/`gsub_modify`.)

Answer (score 4):

Your statement

```
print ".o exists" if ( -f ($file =~ s/\.c$/\.o/gr) )
```

works fine on versions of Perl that support the `/r` modifier—v5.14 or better. (Note that `/g` is superfluous.)

Without it there is no way to apply a substitution without modifying a variable, although you can make it a very short-lived temporary variable using a block

```
{
    (my $doto = $file) =~ s/\.c$/\.o/;
    print ".o exists" if -f $doto;
}
```

Comment: @Gerhard: Given a file name, `*.c`, they want to discover whether the corresponding `*.o` exists. Like a make file, if you like.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it by adding a function as follows.

```
sub doto_exists {
    my $doto = shift;
    $doto =~ s/\.c$/\.o/;
    return (-f $doto);
}

$file = "file1.c";

print ".o exists\n" if doto_exists($file) ;
```

Comment: Note that the best practices for modern Perl suggest snake_case function names. Although we like camels, we don't like CamelCase. ;)

Comment: @simbabque: I have adjusted the answer to reflect snake_case.  I see some discussion on the topic of snake_case vs camelCase for perl. Can you cite a reference link?